# TabWidgets, ListView and many more causes stackoverflow

Tags: android, android-listview, stack-overflow, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I've created an app, a quite complex one. The main class is a `tabhost`, which contains 3 other  `tabhosts` as a widgets. Some tabwidgets contains `listviews`, and one of the lists is causing a problems with a stackoverflow error.

But this kind of error only occurs on gingerbread (not on all devices). I really don't know how to get rid off this error.

Before this I had 3-4 `linearlayouts` in each item in `listview`, but now I instead of this I got a `relativelayout`. This helped, but only for a while.

How is possible that one app is working fine, and another is just constantly crashing?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4321)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6970)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6695)
at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6475)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1657)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1480)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3193)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2588)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6973)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1961)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1600)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1321)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1957)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace that the crash prints to logcat and the code that is mentioned in this stacktrace. Without that we won't be possible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using a row for ListView like bellow layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFE60000">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/header_category_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Category goes here..."
        android:padding="1dp"
        style="@style/offers_group_category">
    </TextView>

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </ViewFlipper>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_dots"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/im_dot_full"
    />
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/im_dot_empty"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I had a ViewFlipper inside FrameLayout, that was working good in almost of devices I tested it, but it was crashing in HTC Wildfire S for instance (All phones with Ghingerbread). So in my case the solution was to take out ViewFlipper from FrameLayout.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I had the same with flipper with, but in my case FlipperView crashed in all devices...

Answer (score 0):

From the stack-trace it seems that some block of code is recursively calling the `android.view.View.draw` method, please post your code for more details

Comment: "Recursively calling" - probably this is listview item. Ive just seen the video with my app crash and maybe I found the solution. There are two options: 1 - too many linearlayouts in listview item (I've changed this is one part of the code and helps) 2 - refreshing function working in background didn't finish fill up the database. So the list creater function calling the empty database and crashing. Will check it. Thanks.